# SSIS Feed Account Numbers From Excel File as Criteria

Tags: excel, variables, ssis, criteria

hoping to be guided in the right direction with this.

I have an Excel sheet with about 7,900 account numbers. I need to feed those account numbers into a SQL query to pull data on those accounts. I would normally be able to just import that into a SQL server but I don't have access to this server to bring the data in for use. I'm having to do this through SSIS.

Is there a way to have SSIS read each row for the account numbers and feed them into my query as a variable?

I haven't tried anything with this yet as this would be the first time trying something like this in SSIS.

Comment: what are you doing the the results?

Comment: also, are you running 7900 queies or are you doing an IN(all account numbers)?

Answer (score 0):

2 different ways to solve your problem:

Process 1. 7900 queries. You would use this approach if you are preparing statements for each account number or something like that.

1. Read excel file into a record set. Create package variable of type object. Excel Source => Recordset destination. This is done in a dataflow.
2. Add a foreach and choose ADO as to what iterate over and add your object variable.
3. Inside foreach object add a function object and build your SQL statement using the account number being iterated through.
4. Add a dataflow to run your sql and do something with the results.

Process 2. all account numbers at the same time. You would do this if you were just getting data back for analysis. This is a much faster way to get results.

1. Load the Excel account numbers into a staging table.
2. Inner Join that staging table into your query to get all results in one response.